# Can I offer two options to a paremeter value?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I would like to do something like to control the "invisble state" of a View.

So I have a function that receive the `View` and there's a optional parameter `invisibleType` that can be `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE`.

I would like to know how can I limit the options of this parameter for these two.
Like `fun makeInvisible(view: View, invisibleType: View.INVISIBLE | View.GONE)`

Can it be done with Kotlin?
Or my best option is create a custom enum or something like that to map the options to View.INVISBLE and View.GONE?

Comment: You can use a sealed class, or an enum.

Comment: @meh Thanks for the reply. I know that I can achieve this with an enum or selead class, abstract class, objects... There's many ways to do this, but I want to know if there's some way that I can do like the ```fun``` in the original question

Comment: There's no language feature for restricting parameter values to a specific set of values. Why not make two functions, `makeInvisible` and `makeGone`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think that the awnser I wanted. Just FYI I can't do this, because the function do some "magic stuff" (The function in the question was just an example). I can follow with the enum approach with no problem, that was just a curiosity that I had

Comment: It is possible with annotations and an IDE plugin that interprets the annotations. That's how the Android annotations like `@DrawableRes` work. But something like that is only worth it if you're working on a library used by thousands of people, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enums or sealed classes to do it but you can use kotlin extension functions for more readability and understanding.

Make 3 extension function on View Object.

```
fun View.visible(): View {
    this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    if (this is Group) {
        this.requestLayout()
    }
    return this
}

fun View.inVisible(): View {
    this.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    if (this is Group) {
        this.requestLayout()
    }
    return this
}

fun View.gone(): View {
    this.visibility = View.GONE
    if (this is Group) {
        this.requestLayout()
    }
    return this
}
```

then you can use like this

```
 mView.layout_photoid_success.gone()
 mView.layoutPhotoReview.visible()
```